# Low fps on phone

Tags: google-play-store, google-account, google, google-play-services

I am currently playing critical ops on letv le 2 which has 3 gb ram and about 650 snapdragon . When i play game ( critical ops ) for few minutes i get about 60 fps  , which runs smoothly . But after some time frames drop from  40 - 20 fps ( most of the time  under 30 fps ) . Which i don't understand why it occurs . It was running smoothly till last 2nd update but after it , it suckssssss. My ram is almost halved free that is approx 1.5 gb . Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Could be any new features that the developer might have added, or just your device getting too hot. Almost every consumer device has a built in thermal management system.